# Get Rows That Have Missing Values between Non-Missing Values

Tags: r

I have a wide dataset with rows representing cases and columns representing months. I'm looking to subset cases that have missing values between columns that don't have missing values.

Not all values are present, so there might be cases with trailing or leading missing values that I would not want to subset. For example, from the following dataset:

```
ID    Month1    Month2    Month3    Month4    Month5    Month6    Month7
1     NA        NA        100       100       NA        200       300
2     300       300       300       400       500       NA        NA
3     150       150       NA        NA        150       150       150
4     NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        100
5     NA        NA        NA        100       100       NA        NA
```

I would only want to subset out the first and third row because they have missing values between columns with non-missing values.

```
ID    Month1    Month2    Month3    Month4    Month5    Month6    Month7
1     NA        NA        100       100       NA        200       300
3     150       150       NA        NA        150       150       150
```

Is there any way to do this in R without converting to long format?

Comment: Row 1 is different from row 2 because it has a missing value between Months 4 and 6, while row 2 does not have any missing values _between_ columns with non-missing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[grep("\\d(NA)+\\d", apply(df[,2:8],1,paste0, collapse="")),]
```

Result:

```
  ID Month1 Month2 Month3 Month4 Month5 Month6 Month7
1  1     NA     NA    100    100     NA    200    300
3  3    150    150     NA     NA    150    150    150
```

The `apply` creates a single string of the contents of the Months columns for each row. The `grep` then looks for cases of NA (or multiple NAs) enclosed within digits. This gives a vector of indices, which is passed to subset `df`.

Comment: This works great! I never would have thought about collapsing the row into a string an then searching for NA values within it. Very elegant solution!